# Recommended approach for associating metadata to content that would lead to relevant search

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, search-results, metadata

I have a question about associating metadata with content. Let say I have a document called purchase order and it has other properties associated with it such as client and year.

So ideally I would create library having 3 columns Name, Client, year (e.g. of row: purchase_order, contoso, 2015).

What if instead of creating separate columns for metadata, I put metadata in file name (e.g. : purchase_order_Contoso_2015) I know by doing this I wont be able to filter and sort but would this improve search ? as sharepoint gives preference to name field during search. In this case it has all metadata within name would this improve search results or search would behave in same way when we have separate columns for metadata ?

Answer (score 0):

In long run below process will help you

1. Create a document content type
2. Create a site column client and add to the content type
3. Create a site column year and add to the content type
4. Go to list settings and attach the newly created content type

Search will capture all the data and it will be easily manageable.

Comment: Thanks amal , I know that approach. My question is second approach that I mentioned : What if instead of creating separate columns for metadata, I put metadata in file name (e.g. : purchase_order_Contoso_2015) I know by doing this I wont be able to filter and sort but would this improve search ? as sharepoint gives preference to name field during search. In this case it has all metadata within name would this improve search results or search would behave in same way when we have separate columns for metadata ? Is this approach useful and recommended ?

Comment: This approach is not recommended. Search will work with your approach as well as the approach I suggested.

Comment: The initial impact of your title change will appear to work, but in time the search engine "learns" what is important. As people use the query search gets better. For example if they are constantly only refining on Year, year will become more relevant.

Comment: So what is you point matthew ? Do you recomed year as separate column or year as part of name ?